# Compiling Bochs on Mac os x Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macos-carbon, bochs

Was someone able to compile the Bochs simulator under Snow Leopard. Leopard worked fine for me but under Snow Leopard I get alot of problems related to the Carbon library...

Ok, some more information was request.

- I compile with make on the shell; stanard build process coming with the bochs sources
- I was successfully able to compile against the 10.5 SDK. Unfortunatley, it was not running under Snow Leopard... always crashed
- then I installed the latest XCode from the SnowLeopard CD and compiled against the 10.6 SDK; withot changing nothing but the isysroot flag to point to the 10.6 instead of 10.5 now the compiler has problems to find some carbon headers... (-framework Carbon is included as a parameter to g++)

Here the error... it fails when it comes to compiling the carbon-based gui for bochs:

```
g++ -c  -I.. -I./.. -I../iodev -I./../iodev -I../instrument/stubs -I./../instrument/stubs -pipe -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -framework Carbon -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -falign-loops=16 -falign-jumps=16 -falign-functions=16 -falign-labels=16 -falign-loops-max-skip=15 -falign-jumps-max-skip=15 -fprefetch-loop-arrays  -fpascal-strings -fno-common -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Dmacintosh -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES    carbon.cc -o carbon.o
carbon.cc:154: warning: non-local variable ‘<anonymous enum> last_screen_state’ uses anonymous type
carbon.cc:154: warning: non-local variable ‘<anonymous enum> screen_state’ uses anonymous type
carbon.cc:163: error: ‘CIconHandle’ does not name a type
carbon.cc: In function ‘OSStatus CEvtHandleWindowBackdropUpdate(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)’:
carbon.cc:278: error: ‘GetWindowPortBounds’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:279: error: ‘BackColor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:280: error: ‘EraseRect’ was not declared in this scope
```

... many more undeclared xxx errors

thanks in advance
Mac

Comment: Are you compiling in 32-bit or 64-bit mode?

Comment: how about improving these tags? osx? Bochs?

Comment: Mac4711: We need much more information. What exact error message do you get? Are you trying to build in Xcode, or using another build system such as make? Please edit your question to include these details.

Answer (score 9):

I was finally able to accomplish this myself, but it took a little more work than I expected. Bochs can be a little temperamental to install, even on Linux.

### Note

Forget about attempting to compile with Carbon. Apple is deprecating it and you won't be able to compile applications in 64-bit with it (the default for Mac OS X). http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/02/18/mountain_lion_focuses_on_cocoa_drops_x11_and_deprecates_carbon

BTW, the Bochs team doesn't use Mac OS X and probably won't be fixing this issue. This could be your chance to help an open source project: http://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/bugs/1204/

That said, you should be able to compile with SDL support with a little tweaking.

### Install the SDL 1.2 Library

I could never get the SDL library from http://www.libsdl.org to work correctly, so I used Homebrew -- http://brew.sh -- to install it:

```
brew install sdl
```

### Configure Bochs

I like to configure Bochs with the debugger (for OS development) and I like to install it into my home directory (in case I want to delete it). Here is the configure command I use:

```
./configure --enable-ne2000 \
            --enable-all-optimizations \
            --enable-cpu-level=6 \
            --enable-x86-64 \
            --enable-vmx=2 \
            --enable-pci \
            --enable-usb \
            --enable-usb-ohci \
            --enable-e1000 \
            --enable-debugger \
            --enable-disasm \
            --disable-debugger-gui \
            --with-sdl \
            --prefix=$HOME/opt/bochs
```

Please note that I added **--disable-debugger-gui** because it is enabled by default if you choose to enable the debugger. However, since the debugger GUI relies on GTK+, and that isn't installed by default on Mac OS X, you want to disable it (GTK+ is another can of worms you don't want to deal with).

### Building and Installing Bochs

Next, build and install

```
make
make install
```

Finally, just set your BXSHARE environment variable and update your path:

```
export BXSHARE="$HOME/opt/bochs/share/bochs"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/opt/bochs/bin"
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to James said (adding the -m32 switch), you may need to add "-arch i386" too.

Here's a modified conf file that I used to build:

```
set echo
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -m32 -pipe -O3 -I/sw/include -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -falign-loops=16 -falign-jumps=16 -falign-functions=16 -falign-labels=16 -falign-loops-max-skip=15 -falign-jumps-max-skip=15 -fprefetch-loop-arrays $CFLAGS"
CPATH="/sw/include"
CPPFLAGS=""
CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -m32 -L/sw/lib"
CXX="g++ -arch i386 -m32"

export CFLAGS
export CPATH
export CPPFLAGS
export CXXFLAGS
export LDFLAGS
export CXX

./configure --enable-sb16 \
     --enable-ne2000 \
     --enable-all-optimizations \
            --enable-cpu-level=6 \
            --enable-x86-64 \
            --enable-sse=2 \
            --enable-pci \
            --enable-acpi \
            --enable-debugger \
            --enable-clgd54xx \
            --enable-usb \
     --enable-plugins \
     ${CONFIGURE_ARGS}
```

Comment: I still get errors like: carbon.cc:2148: error: ‘CreateStandardAlert’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:2153: error: ‘RunStandardAlert’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [carbon.o] Error 1

Answer (score 4):

First, you'll have to run "make dist-clean" to get rid of some of the library code which will have compiled successfully in 64-bit mode - this isn't deleted by a regular "make clean", only the more radical dist-clean. Otherwise, your build will try to mix 32 and 64 bit code, which doesn't work.

Now set CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to contain the -m32 switch to force 32 bit mode. Re-run ./configure, then make, and you should get a working 'bochs' binary.

Having got past the build problems, though, you'll probably find the Carbon version no longer runs; the X11 version seems to be a better bet. (At least, on my Snow Leopard system, the Carbon build fails early with an assertion failure; X11 works as expected.) You may be able to get a 64 bit X11 build running, without the Carbon dependency, but I haven't tried this yet, only 32 bit.

Comment: Are you sure it's `dist-clean` and not `distclean`?

Comment: Peter: Oddly, yes, it is indeed "dist-clean" with the hyphen; like you, I was expecting it to be distclean, which is what I've seen in other projects, but that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Snow Leopard compiles 64-bit by default, but GUI Carbon apps have to be 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Bochs on a 64-bit Mac, you will need to use a different GUI library.  I recommend using X or SDL.

SDL:
To do so, first download and install the LibSDL from http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php, you will need the binaries and development libraries.

After extracting the Bochs source files, run `./configure --with-sdl=path-to-libsdl-dev-files`.

X11:
It should build out of the box: `./configure --with-x11 && make`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way for mac is ....

```
brew install home/x11/bochs
```

I Tried other way for long times..And Failed..
Under MacOS X 10.11

Comment: Not sure it is still accurate, i used `brew install bochs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@user6779

Make sure you do not use the flat unix binary that is created, but rather the Mac OS bundle (called bochs.app).

Eg from the terminal:

```
./bochs.app/Contents/MacOS/bochs
```

And you will no longer receive that assertation.

Answer (score 0):

This how it worked for me under MacOS X 10.10 with Xcode7 developer tools and XQuarz 2.7.7

```
export CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
export CXXFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/X11/lib -lX11
./configure   --enable-debugger --enable-debugger-gui   --enable-all-optimizations    --enable-x86-debugger   --enable-ne2000   --enable-e1000  --enable-pnic   --with-x11  --without-carbon
make
sudo make install
```