# InitCursor(), CreateStandardAlert(), RunStandardAlert() not declared in scope while compiling bochs

Tags: macos, bochs

I was trying to compile bochs the sh .conf.macosx worked but the make command 
resulted in `InitCursor()`, `CreateStandardAlert()`, `RunStandardAlert()` not declared in scope is 
there something obvious that I'm missing on.

Thanx in advance.

--
Srimanth

Comment: This is the error message:
logio.cc:522: error: ‘InitCursor’ was not declared in this scope
logio.cc:542: error: ‘CreateStandardAlert’ was not declared in this scope
logio.cc:543: error: ‘RunStandardAlert’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

Those are deprecated Carbon calls not available in 64 bit binaries. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Dialog_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000200-CH1g-F15644).

If the version of `bochs` you want to compile still depends on those obsolete calls, you need to compile it in the 32 bit mode. You should pass to the compiler and the linker the flag

```
-arch i386
```

to do that on an Intel machine.

After having written that I found that it's a duplicate question, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677324/compiling-bochs-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) :)